# PHP async process communication

Tags: php, multithreading, interprocess, inter-process-communicat

Is there a way to achieve inter-process (or threading) communication in PHP, but still keep everything run asynchronous?

I want to have a script that creates 4 processes and then terminates immediately. Each of the 4 processes should do an action and when finished it should notify someone (another script maybe?) that it finished. So I want to know when all of the 4 scripts are done, so I can update my status from **retrieving** to **done**.

Is this possible? Preferably without re-compiling PHP (I read this is required for working with threads), but I will do that if necessary.

Comment: Why is it necessary that the script creating the process terminates immediately?

Comment: `Preferably without re-compiling PHP (I read this is required for working with threads)` - really? Where? AFAIK it is not possible to multithread PHP, and if you have found a way I would dearly love to know about it...

Comment: @MichaelMior: because I don't want the user to have to wait until the 4 sub-scripts finish, as they take a lot of time.
@DaveRandom: no, native multi-threading is not supported, but http://blog.motane.lu/2009/01/02/multithreading-in-php/ shows how to emulate them, but PHP needs to be re-compiled for `pcntl_fork` to work.

Comment: Then you can simply use `ignore_user_abort()` and flush the output to the browser to allow the script to continue in the background.

Comment: Take a look a this [post][1]

It worked for me

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13690590/599993

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a job queueing system or stick it into CRON. PHP has support for a few job queues, but I have used [Gearman](http://www.gearman.org) in the past and I have written a [custom wrapper around the Linux `at` command](https://github.com/treffynnon/PHP-at-Job-Queue-Wrapper). Both of these could be used to achieve "thread-like" behaviour without recompiling PHP.

Answer (score 4):

As others have mentioned, Gearman is one solution. The other, one I actually prefer, is creating an asynchronous message queue where you add jobs on the job stack.

I'm using [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/) for such purposes, and there's a PHP framework available that implements ZeroMQ for async tasks called [Photon](http://www.photon-project.com/). Browsing Photon's source might give you some ideas on how to implement async job queue in case you decide to go with it.

Answer (score 2):

[Gearman](http://gearman.org) may provide what you are looking for.